# Nested variadic function in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make wrapper using variadic function. However, I got `operand of sizeof may not be a function` error from `func_t func = va_arg(args, func_t);` in Visual studio 2013. Nesting variadic function in C++ is not allowed? or is there any other solution for doing this job?

(I skipped redundant part of A::Outerfunc)

```
int A::Outerfunc(int nargs, ...) {

    if (nargs != 3) {
        cout << "Wrong argument number: " << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    va_list args;

    va_start(args, nargs);
    typedef double func_t(int nargs, ...);

    double *f = va_arg(args, double *);
    func_t func = va_arg(args, func_t);
    double *fprime = va_arg(args, double *);

    va_end(args);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make `func_t` a pointer-to-function, rather than a function....

```
typedef double (*func_t)(int nargs, ...);
```

See http://ideone.com/cF48S7

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I'm lost trying to follow your solution: aren't you passing in a double pointer and retrieving it as pointer to a function that returns a double and takes in a variable number of arguments?

Comment: @DigitalEye: I don't think so... the first call to `va_arg(args, double *)` recovers the first `&d` function argument, then `va_arg(args, func_t)` extracts the `&g` value, then the final `*fprime = va_arg(args, double *)` gets another pointer to `main`'s `d`.  Remember that `va_start(args, X)` arranges for `va_arg` to convert arguments after the argument named `X`....